# Alter Woocommerce product name when price is on sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

We use "NET" to identify products that are on sale. I have written the following code to automatically add or remove NET to/from products as they go on or off sale.

```
function change_product_titles( $post, $title ) {
    
    if ( !empty( get_post_meta( $post->get_id, '_sale_price', true ))){
        return $title.' NET';
    }else{
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_title', 'change_product_titles', 10, 2 );
```

This seems pretty simple, but I am not seeing the desired effect anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea. Why would you put this info into the product _name_? AFAIK WooCoomerce already comes with a mechanism to mark products as "on sale", so why are you creating your own solution to an already solved problem here now ...?

Comment: This is how the business has operated for decades, and it's standard practice in the horticultural sales industry. It also lets our invoicing staff know which items are on sale since they are not eligible for additional discounts.

Comment: But if the information is already stored in a meta field `_sale_price`, then you should not need to persist (and therefor also constantly _manipulate_) it in a second place, right? Should be enough to modify the product titles whenever they get _output_ anywhere. So I would go look into the filters for that; your additional problem with the quick edits "hanging" might perhaps also already disappear, if you stop manipulating the actual database contents.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution. Do you have any insight on where I might get started?

Comment: `woocommerce_product_title` would probably be the most promising hook/filter candidate.

Comment: I have updated the code, and indeed this does seem like a much simpler solution, however it is not affecting product titles displayed anywhere.

Comment: `woocommerce_product_title` is not the right hook to be used for this purpose… See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the right hook and the right way… Try the following instead, that will add a suffix to the product title (and the product name) **everywhere**, when the product is on sale, without any need of constantly updating the product titles:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_title', 10, 2 );
function change_product_title( $post_title, $post_id ) {
    if( get_post_type($post_id) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && $product->get_sale_price() > 0 ) {
            $post_title .= ' NET';
        }
    }
    return $post_title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
function change_product_name( $name, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_sale_price() > 0 ){
        $name .= ' NET';
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

You will need to remove "NET" from your product titles in the admin.

Comment: Confirmed works.

Comment: I also need to mark 'NET' any products with the tag 'Hard Goods'. I tried adding an else if statement with the has_tag function, but I can't get it to work. Is this not the proper function for this purpose? I created a new question to display the full code.

Comment: I have answered your other question for 'Hard Goods' product tag…