# Alter Woocommerce product name for specific product tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

Following [Alter Woocommerce product name when price is on sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127593/alter-woocommerce-product-name-when-price-is-on-sale/77128478#77128478) answer code to one of my previous questions, that append product names based on sale price.

Now, I am trying to add the same feature for products with a particular product tag:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_title', 10, 2 );
function change_product_title( $post_title, $post_id ) {
    if( get_post_type($post_id) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && $product->get_sale_price() > 0 ) {
            $post_title .= ' NET';
        }else if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && has_tag( $tag = 'Hard Goods', $post = null ) ){
            $post_title .= 'NET';
        }
    }
    return $post_title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
function change_product_name( $name, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_sale_price() > 0 ){
        $name .= ' NET';
    }else if( has_tag( $tag = 'Hard Goods', $post = null )){
        $name .= ' NET';
    }
    return $name;
}
```

This code is not producing the desired effect. I have never used the has_tag function, and I'm not sure if it's appropriate for this scenario. I have tried using several versions of the tag name (hard-goods, Hard_Goods, etc.) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `has_term()` WordPress conditional function to target product tag(s) as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_title', 10, 2 );
function change_product_title( $post_title, $post_id ) {
    if( get_post_type($post_id) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        if( ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && $product->get_sale_price() > 0 ) 
        || has_term( 'Hard Goods', 'product_tag', $post_id ) ) {
            $post_title .= ' NET';
        }
    }
    return $post_title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_name', 'change_product_name', 10, 2 );
function change_product_name( $name, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_sale_price() > 0 || has_term( 'Hard Goods', 'product_tag', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $name .= ' NET';
    }
    return $name;
}
```

It should work.

You should better use a product tag **slug** or **term ID** instead of the name.

Comment: Confirmed working.